# Drifting with the VehicleBody3D in Godot 4

Tags: godot, drift, racing

I am working on a racing game and I have tried to make a drifting system, but I have failed and it takes too much effort to drift the car when actually playing the game. I'm looking for a arcade drifting system that can actually be used on a race track. I'll appreciate any solutions!

I tried setting the front wheel traction higher than the back wheel traction, but then I had to actually turn the car to get in in position for the drift then turn the car back like how you would drift a car in real life. The car instantly destabilized and went off the track. I have also tried bringing down all of the wheel traction, but then the car just went in the same direction when I turned the car, but the velocity slowly went to match the direction the car was pointed in. That is not real drifting and I am looking for something that is easy to use, realistic, and actually works.

Comment: I've heard that not using the vehicle body and instead using a rigid body sphere for the physics and having the car model and animations just for show is a good way to go, but it is something I have not experimented with, I no advice on implementing it.

Comment: That would work, but I want something that's actually realistic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.